# Keras error: "If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument (instead of the `batch_size` argument.....)

Tags: python, keras

I want to use a custom loss function, by extracting features from the penultimate layer of VGG16 network. So, in the model.compile() function, I pass a function vgg_loss() which returns the required loss. It is shown below:

```
model_loss = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=input_size)
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = lrate, decay = 1e-6), loss = vgg_loss(model_loss))
```

The vgg_loss() function is defined as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.backend import reshape
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

def vgg_loss(model):

    def loss(gt, pred):
        print(" Inside loss function ")    

        pred = reshape(pred, (1,) + (128,128,3))
        gt = reshape(gt, (1,) + (128,128,3))

        gt_in = preprocess_input(gt)
        pred_in = preprocess_input(pred)

        pred_out = model.predict(pred_in)
        gt_out = model.predict(gt_in)

        return K.mean(K.mean((pred_out - gt_out)**2, axis = (1,2)), axis = 1)

    return loss
```

When run model.compile, I get the following error related to the usage of symbolic tensors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Dell\.spyder-py3\UNet_keras\train_SO.py", line 32, in <module>
model = unet(input_size = (height,width,nc))

File "C:\Users\Dell\.spyder-py3\UNet_keras\model_SO.py", line 68, in unet
loss = vgg_loss(model_loss), metrics = ['mse'])

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\envs\viji_aip\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 229, in 
compile
self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\envs\viji_aip\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 692, in 
_prepare_total_loss
y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\envs\viji_aip\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 71, in __call__
losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\envs\viji_aip\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 132, in call
return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Dell\.spyder-py3\UNet_keras\data_SO.py", line 28, in loss
pred_out = model.predict(pred)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\envs\viji_aip\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1464, 
in predict
callbacks=callbacks)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\envs\viji_aip\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 
250, in predict_loop
steps_name='steps')

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\envs\viji_aip\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 
571, in check_num_samples
'you should specify the `' + steps_name + '` argument '

ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the `steps` argument 
(instead of the `batch_size` argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of 
input data).
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to use `tensorflow-2` instead of `keras`.
2. You can't add anything in the loss function and expect it to work, it must be differentiable. You may not need to add preprocessing_input of vgg16 inside the loss, your output from the model shouldn't be perfect images (with range 0-255), they should be already normalized tensors (due to some activations like `sigmoid`). (Make sure, the VGG16 you're using was also trained with same normalization scheme (0-1) range, as the output from the network will probably pass through an activation function like `sigmoid`, your output will most likely be in the range(0-1))

Here's a simple model with the loss function of yours:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.applications import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

def vgg_loss(model):

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(K.square(model(y_pred) - model(y_true)), axis=-1)
    return loss

input_size = (224,224,3)
model_loss = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=input_size)

# simple model

ip = Input(input_size)
base_model = Dense(3)(ip)

model = Model(ip, base_model)

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = vgg_loss(model_loss))
```

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 224, 224, 3)       12        
=================================================================
Total params: 12
Trainable params: 12
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: That worked, thks! As a followup: When you said "they should be normalized tensors", were you referring to the inputs to vgg? If yes, what range should they be normalized to?

Comment: That depends on the network structure, you can add few batch-norm layers, the loss function gets the actual output from the model, as you pass your output to vgg, that means your model predicts something related to an image, maybe an image itself or a mask, you can normalize the output in 0-1 range while training, that will make sure the vgg_loss gets 0-1 range tensors. You can simply divide the output by 255. like we regularly do with input images.

Comment: It is bad advice to ignore normalization, you cannot just remove it and expect the model to always work the same way, it could break in unexpected ways and still "appear to work", specially if you use saturating activations.

Comment: I didn't say anywhere to avoid normalization, I said if your output is normalized don't do it again. These two are completely different statements. Also, the answer just shows how to use vgg inside the loss function, you can't expect an answerer to completely know all the perfect information like (model output, activations, etc) when those were not mentioned., so ignoring the pre_processing part just makes it more reasonable than just blindly adding it there without knowing the actual scenario.