# What is the role of preprocess_input() function in Keras VGG model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This question is kind of a follow up for the discussion in comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768062/3337089).

From what I understand, the `preprocess_input()` function does mean subtraction and std-dev dvision for the input images. The mean are those that are computed on ImageNet-1K database when training VGG.

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768062/3337089) says that when using VGG features as a loss function, `preprocess_input()` is not required and we just need to normalize the image to `[0,1]` range before passing to VGG. This confuses me...

1. If we don't preprocess, then the input will be in different range compared to those images used to train VGG. How are the VGG features still valid?
2. From what I understand from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556342/3337089), we should have images in `[0,255]` range and `preprocess_input()` function takes care of the normalization and all. From the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L158-L229), I understand that for caffe models, normalization to `[0,1]` range is not done. Instead mean is subtracted and std-dev is divided. How would just normalizing network output to `[0,1]` range as suggested in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768062/3337089) achieve the same?

**Edit 1**:
I'm considering the models which output images. It is not specific to a single model. One example is image denoising network. The input to my network is a noisy image and its output is a denoised image. I want to minimize MSE between denoised image and ground truth image in VGG feature space. Whatever be the range of my network's output, I can easily change it to `[0,255]` by multiplying by appropriate factors. Similarly I can do any preprocessing required on my network's output (subtract mean, divide by std-dev).

Empirically I found that the output of preprocess function is in approx range `[-128,151]`. So VGG network is trained on images in this range. Now, if I feed it with images (or tensors from my network output) in the range `[0,1]`, convolution would be fine but biases will cause problem right? To elaborate, for images in range `[-128,151]`, a layer of VGG network may have learnt a bias of 5. When I feed an image in the range `[-1,1]` to the VGG network, the bias disrupts everything, right?

I'm not training VGG model. I'm using the weights from the model trained on ImageNet-1k database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you should not ignore or change the normalization of the data in which a model was trained. It could break the model in unexpected ways and since you are using the features in another learning model, it appears to work, but you have now hidden any changes in performance.

This is true specially for models that use saturating activations, for example with a ReLU you might get more zeros than with using normalized data.

Answer to your specific questions:

1. Yes features would be in a different range for VGG and other networks, whether they are valid is another issue, there is a performance loss since normalization was not used.
2. Changing the normalization scheme does not produce the same kind of normalization as the original, so it is not achieving the same. The code in the answer works but conceptually it is not doing the right thing.

Comment: The VGG, in this case, will get output from a model, not exact image inputs, so isn't it fair to assume the output will pass through some activation like `sigmoid`. So, using the pre-processing inside the loss before passing to VGG will break the code even more than what it is right now don't you think?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi The OP does not mention getting inputs from another model, I think you are confusing this question with one of the questions linked in this question. I am actually answering the questinon as it was asked.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes, my understanding is that we have to follow the same normalization steps at test time, which were done at training time. So, not preprocessing doesn't feel right to me. You also say that `The code in the answer works but conceptually it is not doing the right thing`. How would it work? The VGG features would not make any sense right? I've updated my question with an example of how normalizing to range `[-1,1]` would break because of the bias.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN My answer already mentions how it would work, for example with ReLU outputs it would produce more zeros (more sparse features) than normalizing correctly. In the end it should not matter, you should always use normalized inputs if the model was trained on normalized data

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi, my network outputs images only. I can easily change the range from `[0,1]` to `[0,255]` by multiplying by 255, right? Then preprocessing won't break anything.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, can you please elaborate on that? I didn't understand how having sparse features compensates for not preprocessing.

Comment: You are completely misusing my answer as an example. My answer was clearly focused on using VGG inside loss function and nothing else. Obviously, the common idea is you'll normalize images (either manually or using the function from keras), using a model inside loss function is a completely different idea.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN No,  what I am saying is that not using pre-processed inputs will produce more sparse features (more zeros) in comparison to using the right pre-preprocessed inputs, in the case of outputs with the ReLU activation. You would change how the activation behaves as you change the output range due to the lack of pre-processing/normalization

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi It is sensible to ask why in your answer you were not applying pre-processing, which can be applied symbolically inside the loss, which is what this question is asking.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, thank you, I understood. I have heard from my fellow colleagues that without preprocessing, the accuracy of VGG network didn't drop significantly. (Accuracy with 1000 class predictions). I would imagine that without preprocessing, VGG predictions would go haywire. Have you noticed the same trend anywhere else? What would be the reason for this... I'll verify this claim myself and ask a follow-up question. Just wanted to know if you have encountered this before.

Comment: Please read the answer again, I clearly told I didn't have any idea about the actual model from the question that was mentioned, there vgg receives output from another model (which probably has some `sigmoid` activation in the last layer), so it's useless to do any processing on output which will be in range (0,1). OP is making extending discussion from an answer which was written in a different context.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN I cannot comment no specific experiments without all the details. If you use ImageNet pre-trained VGG and predict with it, without pre-processing the predictions will not make any sense.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Okay. Thank you. I'll validate that claim myself and if it is found to be true, I'll ask a follow up question.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer:

> In the referenced question, OP uses VGG inside a loss function, the loss function gets
>   the output from a model (unfortunately, OP didn't share his model),
>   usually the output passes through an activation function like
>   `sigmoid`, hence it was mentioned the output will be already
>   normalized tensor. Whereas, preprocess_input assumes you have images
>   with range 0-255., using this function inside the loss is complete a
>   waste (you can't apply some normalization on tensors with a range 0-1
>   (after activation) that was supposed to be applied on images with
>   range (0-255)). That's the basic reason why it was discouraged to use
>   the function inside the loss (also you can't add any
>   non-differentiable operations inside loss).

But what you can do is change the range to match that of the actual VGG preprocessing function. (making the tensors zero mean with range -1 to 1)

> Are the features valid? - that completely depends on what OP is trying
>   for the task that's being solved and the model. Even with all those
>   details, it'll take some research and looking into the weights to
>   decide.

Comment: Here you seem to be answer a different question, please remember to answer what was asked here, not in a different question.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi `preprocess_input()` function works for [symbolic tensors](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L232-L284) as well. So, I guess it is differentiable. Even if not, I can manually do those operations - mean subtraction and division by std-dev. I've updated my question, hopefully it clears some concerns you had.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN you're repeatedly misreading the situation and context, the mentioned answer has a different context where the model and the final activation is unknown. If the output is in range (0,1), and you use preprocess_input, you'll completely destroy the output making everything almost 0. That's the common-sense behind it. I guess there's no need to extend with these unnecessary discussion which is totally out of place.